# How can I get the Share menu option to let users add a caption?

Tags: google-mirror-api

I'm using the Share menu option on a card, but it's not having the ability to add a caption.
Anything I should do to enable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, as of [XE10](https://developers.google.com/glass/release-notes#xe10) you needed to add a list of [sharingFeatures](https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/contacts#sharingFeatures) to the Contact you want to share with. In JSON form you need to add

```
"sharingFeatures": ["ADD_CAPTION"]
```

to the Contact. So the full Contact might look something like

```
{
  "displayName": "Some Body",
  "imageUrls": [
    "http://example.com/somebody.jpg"
  ],
  "sharingFeatures": [
    "ADD_CAPTION"
  ]
}
```

Since you're using Java, make sure you have the latest library (v1-rev40-1.17.0-rc as of the time I post this), available at https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/mirror/v1, which does have [Contact.setSharingFeatures()](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/mirror/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/mirror/model/Contact.html#setSharingFeatures%28java.util.List%29)

Comment: doesn't seem like the java mirror api jar has added this. Is it in there?

Comment: I'm using v1-rev26-1.17.0-rc